# Working with RS232 used by multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am attempting to write a class that represents the communication with a device over a RS232 connection. This device can both be read from and wrote to, which can be done by multiple threads.

So far I have opted to make the class a singleton class because it makes sense that only one connection to the device should ever exist. I have also implemented two interfaces `IDataProvider` and `IDataConsumer`. These simply define the methods `Boolean ReadData(out Object readData, params Object[] args)` and `WriteData(Object inData, params Object[] args)`. Along with the interface I have also written `RS232Device`. This implements methods that `Open()`, `Close()`, `Read()`, and `Write()` to the port.

Below is my class outline so far.

```
public class DeviceIO : RS232Device, IDataProvider, IDataConsumer
{
    public static DeviceIO Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<DeviceIO> lazyInstance 
        = new Lazy<DeviceIO>(() => new DeviceIO());

    private DeviceIO() : base() {}

    public void ConfigurePort(SerialPortConfig inConfig)
    {
        Configure(inConfig);
    }

    public Boolean ReadData(out Object readData, params Object[] args)
    {
        readData = null;
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean WriteData(Object inData, params Object[] args)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My question now is how I make this thread-safe. I would assume that within `ReadData` and `WriteData` I would lock on some instance of an `Object`. Is that all that I would need to do? Basically just as the modifications below?

Could I take the `Instance` below and distribute it to various threads and not have any issues where two threads might try to write to the device simultaneously?

```
public class DeviceIO : RS232Device, IDataProvider, IDataConsumer
{
    public static DeviceIO Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<DeviceIO> lazyInstance
        = new Lazy<DeviceIO>(() => new DeviceIO());

    private static readonly Object Schlage = new Object();

    private DeviceIO() : base() {}

    public void ConfigurePort(SerialPortConfig inConfig)
    {
        lock(Schlage)
        {
            Configure(inConfig);
        }
    }

    public Boolean ReadData(out Object readData, params Object[] args)
    {
        lock (Schlage)
        {
            readData = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean WriteData(Object inData, params Object[] args)
    {
        lock (Schlage)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct.  Side note: Your `Schlage` variable doesn't have to be `static`.

Comment: One more question, most of the time when trying to query a serial device you first write something to the RS232 then read a line of data back. If I enter the `ReadData` method and obtain a lock, can I call `WriteData` and not deadlock myself?

Comment: `lock` will only prevent **OTHER** threads from entering once the lock has been established.  From within the **same** thread, going from ReadData() to WriteData() will not block, and will not cause an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that this type of scenario is better served by implementing a message-queue pattern. Here, any code that needs to use the RS232 facility would queue a request to the queue, and wait for a reply or reaction. Meanwhile, exactly one thread would serve the business-end of that queue, taking them off the queue one at a time, executing it by sending and/or receiving information from the RS232 port, and then proceeding on to the next queued message.

This helps simplify your code-flow, and helps prevent deadlocks. All of the code that actually accesses the RS232 resource executes on exactly one thread (your queue-servicing thread). As for all of the other threads, they have only to post their request to the queue -- a very fast operation, and then check-back for their response.

One way to implement this would be:

```
_myMessageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Rs232Message>();
```

post new messages to your message-queue thusly:

```
_myMessageQueue.Enqueue( message );
```

and you retrieve the queued messages with:

```
bool isOk = _myMessageQueue.TryDequeue( out message );
```

Comment: I like this idea and eventually came to a solution somewhat akin to a mix between this and what I had suggested in the OP. Seeing as no one else wanted to answer this in the past two years, you get the chicken dinner.